# Discord SDK client.guilds.channels.values is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to develop a command that allows the user to send a certain message on all text channels, this is what I did:

```js
     else if(command == 'snd') {
            if(suffix == 'all'){
        
                    let channels = client.guilds.channels;
                    for (const channel of channels.values()) 
                    {
                        message.guild.channels.cache.get(channel.id).send(sParameter[1])
                    }  
            }
        }
```

So, I run this command:

`! sir snd all -test`

and I get this error:

```sh
 for (const channel of channels.values())
                                ^
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'values' of undefined
     at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\utente\Desktop\bouncerBot\main.js:159:48)
     at Client.emit (node:events:394:28)
     at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\utente\Desktop\bouncerBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:18)
     at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\utente\Desktop\bouncerBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
     at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\utente\Desktop\bouncerBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:345:31)
     at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\utente\Desktop\bouncerBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:443:22)
     at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\utente\Desktop\bouncerBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:300:10)
     at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\utente\Desktop\bouncerBot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
     at WebSocket.emit (node:events:394:28)
     at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\utente\Desktop\bouncerBot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:970:20)
     at Receiver.emit (node:events:394:28)
     at Receiver.dataMessage (C:\Users\utente\Desktop\bouncerBot\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:517:14)
     at Receiver.getData (C:\Users\utente\Desktop\bouncerBot\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:435:17)
     at Receiver.startLoop (C:\Users\utente\Desktop\bouncerBot\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:143:22)
     at Receiver._write (C:\Users\utente\Desktop\bouncerBot\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:78:10)
     at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:389:12)
```

Could anyone tell me why I'm getting that error? I am using `discord.js 13.0.1`

Edit:

```
C:\Users\utente\Desktop\bouncerBot\main.js:158
                channel.send(sParameter[1])
                        ^

TypeError: channel.send is not a function
    at C:\Users\utente\Desktop\bouncerBot\main.js:158:25
    at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\utente\Desktop\bouncerBot\main.js:157:36)
    at Client.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\utente\Desktop\bouncerBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:18)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\utente\Desktop\bouncerBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\utente\Desktop\bouncerBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:345:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\utente\Desktop\bouncerBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:443:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\utente\Desktop\bouncerBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:300:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\utente\Desktop\bouncerBot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\utente\Desktop\bouncerBot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:970:20)
    at Receiver.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at Receiver.dataMessage (C:\Users\utente\Desktop\bouncerBot\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:517:14)
    at Receiver.getData (C:\Users\utente\Desktop\bouncerBot\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:435:17)
    at Receiver.startLoop (C:\Users\utente\Desktop\bouncerBot\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:143:22)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is where you are wrong:

- `client.guilds` returns a collection of cached guilds with the client so you may access the channels directly as `client.channels` since they are available to your cache seperately ( cause of it being undefined ) , now the collection needs the object as whole to send a `Message` to, so you may not need the `Object.values()` of it and need to access their IDs each time that is just ineffecient you can create a `for` loop directly. How?, Let me show you!

```js
    client.channels.cache.forEach( channel => {
    channel.send(sParameter[1])
    });
```

**Also note that if there are more guilds your bot is in then you may not be able to fetch the channels from Message#Guild since they would be unavailable to that guild so your logic completely falsey**

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer. I tried your code. I get this error: `channels is not iterable`

Comment: My bad! client.channels returns a collection as I mentioned before, you can try using a forEach loop, edited!

Comment: now i am getting this error: channels.forEach is not a function

Comment: It has been changed to client.channels.cache.forEach as of v12

Comment: But now I get another error but this time in sending the message -> channel.send is not a function

Comment: Can you console log channel and show me what's up?

Comment: Please add console.log(channel)'s output to yoru question I don't see any updates

Comment: Sorry right there! I forgot voice channels exist lmao could you please add a simple check like ```if(channel.type == "text") {  channel.send(sParameter[1]) }``` that should solve it

Comment: Now it does not give errors but in compensation it does not send messages to the server channels

Comment: Could you try replacing `text` with `GUILD_TEXT` all capital

Comment: Now it works, the problem is that it sends it to all the server channels it belongs to. Do you think there is a way to send the message only in all channels of the current server? (i.e. the server where the command to send the message is given)

Comment: For this question, however, I will put you as a solution, then I will ask another one for how to be able to send messages on all the channels of the server in which the command was sent